# Подготовка к работе "Программист"

Tags: работа

Всем привет, вот скажите когда можно идти работать программистом, в какую-нибудь компанию? Вот сидишь,читаешь литературу, учишься, обучаешься, но вот когда наступает тот порог который надо переступить и можно идти работать программистом? Просто я вот спрашивал друзей, у них такая ерунда "Мне всё время кажется что я не смогу т.к не достаточно опытен".

Comment: ищешь вакансии => проходишь собеседование => выполняешь тестовое задание => идёшь работать, естественно я утрирую, но метод действенный

Comment: А сколько примерно надо учить ЯП, чтобы выйти на нормальный уровень, чтобы не прдти опозорится и уйти...?

Comment: скорее всего, когда будите искать вакансии, увидите и требования, что претендент **должен** уметь/иметь/знать, и что желательно уметь/иметь/знать

Comment: А где есть сайты, на который много работы(там где ищут работников) хочу посмотреть на примерный требования.

Comment: "А сколько примерно надо учить ЯП, чтобы выйти на нормальный уровень, чтобы не прдти опозорится и уйти...?" - если вам будут задавать много вопросов и вы не будете знать ответа это еще не позор. а вот если вас действительно попытаюсь ткнуть лицом в лужу то туда вообще идти не стоит.

к сожалению времена когда надо было знать один язык уже давно прошли. если вы поищите вакансии для девелоперов то заметите что кроме языка от них требуют еще знания многих технологий. найдите любую вакансию, которая вам понравится, попытайтесь разобратся со всеми технологиями которые там указаны

Comment: программист это человек который часто пишет программы в разных областях (напр. наука/медицина/экономика) поэтому он должен уметь находить нужную информацию. 

этот вопрос на сайте уже разжовывался неоднократно, - используйте поиск сайта. если поиск у сайта не очень, - можно гуглить так: `hashcode программирование junior`

Comment: Работайте на open source проектами (чтобы уметь работать в команде, плюс потенциальный работодатель мог посмотреть код) - не обязательно большими даже. Будет портфолио - работа сама найдет.

Answer (score 19):

Мой рецепт такой:

1. Надо поставить себе какую-нить задачку - ну скажем написать калькулятор (для десктопников) или там счетчик посещений (для веб девелоперов), ну в общем некую ерунду. Главное чтобы вы все 100% написали сами - никаких копи-пейстов. Я вам гарантирую как только напишете все встанет на свои места и появится хоть какая-то уверенность в себе.
2. После того как получили некую уверенность в себе - пишем резюме/CV. Как писать это отдельная тема - но смысл резюме не в том, чтобы расхвалить себя (это тоже надо), а в том, чтобы выйти на интервью - это первично.
3. Рассылаем резюме штук по 10 в день. Здесь выхлоп должен быть такой: на 10 резюме - 1 интервью. Если КПД меньше, значит что-то не так написали - перепишите.
4. Идем на интервью. Цель интервью конечно устроиться на работу, но это макроцель. Миницель - это установить эмоциональный контакт с интервьюером - если будет нормальный контакт возьмут на работу даже если знаний недостаточно. А если не будет нормального контакта, будь вы хоть Билл Гейтс - не видать вам работы. Во время интервью вам как начинающему важно акцентироваться на 2-х вещах. Первое: вы способны самообучаться (программирование требует постоянного самообучения), второе: вы член команды (программирование коллективный вид работы). Делать упор на то, что вы все знаете - это нереально - любой нормальный интервьюер завалит любого гуру. Сам сколько раз валил таких всезнаек :). И еще помните - важно зацепиться, ну то есть не ищите работу за мульон, что-то похожее на бабки - беритесь. А будет некий job record уже проще раскрутиться.

В общем где-то так. Удачи!

Answer (score 14):

Как уже писали выше - в любом случае разместить резюме необходимо. Единственное что я не согласен с тем что нужно искать работу только тогда когда ты уже знаешь все перечисленные там технологии и т.д. Более того, как уже писали выше, знание мат и практической части никак не освобождает вас от интервью и если вы не понравитесь интервьюеру - ваша попытка обречена на провал.

По поводу "сколько нужно учить язык" и т.д. - учить язык нужно все время, не искать работу пока ты не будешь хорошо знать язык - это банально глупо. Причин этому несколько, во первых  знание языка не дает тебе гарантии в трудоустройстве, во вторых учить его можно очень долго, возможно ты даже достигнешь уровня middle еще не имея опыта работы, но, в таком случае, тебе все-равно прийдеться  подыматься по карьерной лестнице с низу ( есть вероятность что нет, но скорее всего именно так ).

Соответственно искать работу можно уже сейчас ( даже если ты практически не знаешь языка или необходимых технологий ).  Это дает тебе 2 очень важные вещи, а именно:

- опыт интервью ( соответственно как только ты "выростешь" до работы, ты быстро возьмешь быка за рога т.к. интервью для тебя будет не в новинку и ты будешь иметь некий опыт  )
- шанс найти первую работу очень быстро
- не относящийся к твоему случаю, но тем не менее укажу - шанс найти работу мечты

Как уже писали выше - важно зацепиться, но это не означает что нужно работать за еду ( хотя у многих первая работа программистом была именно такая =) ), причина этому проста - ты выбрал 'hard core' путь программиста, ты изучил 100500 методик, шаблонов, перечитал 100500 книг, потратил 100500 часов на написание кода (и т.д.) и ты не хочешь получать за это столько сколько получают продавцы на рынке. ( во всяком случае если ты уважаешь себя ).

Как видишь все предельно просто - продолжай изучать и любить программирование и терроризируй работодателей в поисках работы и опыта интервью. И помни - под лежачий камень вода не бежит

Answer (score 11):

По-моему, на Junior Developer многого знать не надо. Достаточно иметь базу (**основные** структуры данных и алгоритмы), уметь программировать на каком-либо языке на уровне чуть выше университетских заданий. А также понимать и применять принципы ООП (в случае использования другой парадигмы, соответственно, её). Вот этих трёх пунктов достаточно, если отбросить всякое там "желание развиваться" и "умение самостоятельно обучаться" и прочие общеизвестные вещи, применимые к любой профессии.

Answer (score 10):

ну в моем случае хронология была такой:

1. армия
2. 0 (ноль) знаний
3. один год изучения Delphi в технаре и самостоятельно
4. Практика на предприятии
5. Решил попробовать устроиться на работу. Искал объявления в интернете. Нашел что-то непонятное. Пошел на собеседование. Понял, что я нихрена не знаю :) Меня взяли на испытательный срок, я делал какие-то простенькие программы, самостоятельно изучал ООП, делал кое-какие проекты для "набивания руки". Меня постепенно подготовили к основному проекту. За 4 месяца работы я заработал чуть больше, чем ничего, и свалил оттуда, когда понял, что я уже что-то понимаю, что мне тут платить не собираются нормально, ну естественно не просто так ушел, а на другую, уже перспективную работу, где нынче и пребываю.

Главное - это не лениться, и изучать все самостоятельно. И конечно же не бояться "прыгнуть выше головы" ;)

Comment: Да но первый раз.... вообще страшно! А есть ли какие-нибудь группы начинающих программистов, где все работают бесплатно, но получают опыт работы например в команде, под начальством... и.т.д

Comment: если вы прийдёте на фирму и скажите, что хотите работать бесплатно, вас возможно возьмут как "интерна"

Comment: Только зачем? Если с большой долей вероятности вас могут взять на младшего разработчика, какой смысл предлагаться бесплатно? Скорее всего вы себя недооцениваете, потому что любому стажеру всё равно хоть немного да платят.

Comment: набраться опыта и пройти интервью на более "престижное" место?

Comment: Да но я ооочень не уверен в своих знаниях... если вдруг скажут сделай то, а ты этого **не** можешь сделать... худо будет.

Comment: Освойте базу, все знать всеравно не возможно. В том случае если вам дают подобное задание отправляетесь в гугл и ищете ответ, скорей всего там есть то что нужно.

Comment: Если тебя взяли на работу, зная, что ты только учишься, и не готов приступить к серьезной работе, и если начальник более-менее соображающий человек, то никаких серьезных заданий, в первое время, давать не будут. Сначала тебя поднатаскают, и понемногу будут приобщать к работе.

Answer (score 4):

Все будет нормально, если постоянно самосовершенствоваться, постоянно учиться. Даже в период поиска работы, искать для своего мозга работу, чтобы занять его мыслительным процессом. Языки программирования все не охватить, так как нельзя объять необъятное, довольствоваться тем, что знаешь и расширять базу познаний в рамках разумного. Успех будет тогда, когда придет уверенность в чем-то одном, затем во втором.

В резюме честно писать багаж своих знаний, чтобы найти работу, где можно начать подъем наверх по ступенькам, по этапам саморазвития, как программиста.